# mobicent diamater with asterik , freepbx

Tags: asterisk, freeswitch

I have already used Ericsson Ericsson Diameter SDK to check the charging system
from below example:

http://www.mobicents.org/diameter_event_charging.html 
Can any one guide how how i put mobicent dimameter with my freepbx, asterik to charge a call?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk have no diameter support

Radius support availible.

So only way do something with diameter is use fastagi interface and diamter libs(for example for c++ http://diameter.sourceforge.net/ ) to get needed requests and response. For more info see mobicents.org docs.

Note, you can't do that on freepbx without significant dialplan modification. Very likly you will need help of freepbx.org expert + highly skilled c/c++ person